# Folder location for images in android app

Tags: android, mobile-application

I am creating an app, the purpose of the app is for you to import copies of photos from your phones gallery and associate info against the photo, such as a description, notes etc.

The info will be stored a a dB with paths to the files. Within the app the user can  select different photos, where you'll be taken to a new screen that shows the photo and the saved info below it.

I am unsure what is the best place to store the images on the device. Internal storage or external public storage. The downside of internal would  be all images are lost when the app is uninstalled, I'm no sure if a user would expect their photos to be deleted on uninstall? That could make a user very upset if they are important photos to them.

Android seem to be pushing you to store data with the apps own sandbox which is deleted on uninstall with Android 11.

Any advice or thoughts?

Comment: You did not tell how and where you would store the info.

Comment: More info has now been added which hopefully gives a better overview of the app.

Comment: And storing file and info using MediaStore would not fit you?

Comment: This is a react native project there doesn't seem to be a library that allows you to use media store yet.